# add element to xml file with xerces

Tags: c++, dom, xerces

i have an xml file named LOD.xml and in this file there is a list of models.

i want to add another DomElement to this file. i dont want to parse all the list again. i just want to parse file and get DomDocument and RootDomElement.

after appending my new DomElement to the RootDomElement, i want to write DomDocument to this file back again.

do you know how i can do this??

i use xerces and c++

Answer (score 0):

There is an article on XML serialization using Xerces-C++ on [IBMs developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-serial.html), `LocalFileFormatTarget` is what you are looking for.